# How can I keep the terminal output always at the beginning?

Tags: command-line, scrollbar

I have large output from a python script that clear the terminal and print again, but the scrollbar of terminal always is in the bottom.
[image: screenshot showing long output]

Is it possible to fix the scrollbar to the top so I could always see the beginning of the output like this:

[image: Image 2]

I need the terminal to be continuously updating but it shouldn't scroll down to the end, I need to always see the top of the output even while it is updating.

Command example:

[image]

Comment: Simply due to how terminal is implemented, it's always going to scroll down to the bottom and the last lines/characters. So always keeping first few lines on screen  may be possible but it cuts against how terminals actually work and may be difficult to implement.  Use `less` or `more` or another pager software as terdon's answer suggests.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you just want to use a pager like `less` or `more`:

```
$ seq 1 1000 | less
```

You can scroll up and down with the arrow keys and, when you've finished, hit <kbd>q</kbd> to exit. You can also search using <kbd>/</kbd>. See `man less` for details.

Alternatively, you can use `head` to only see the first few lines. For example

```
$ seq 1 1000 | head
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but the problem is that the script always is update the terminal so this process never end. I can't run "seq python script.py | head". What I want is for the terminal to continue updating is to be able to see always up and also thanks for the grammar corrections.

Comment: @sebastianmorales This information should be part of the question. Please click "edit" button under your question and add this. Otherwise question is incomplete and unclear.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I do it. Ty

Comment: @sebastianmorales it would also help if you could give an example of a specific command you use that does this. I can't think of any tool that behaves as you describe but which doesn't already do this buffering for you. For example, `top` will continuously update without scrolling down, but it is designed that way.

Comment: @terdon I add a image in the body question with a small table, what I want to see is the header like block the scrollbar on the top.

Comment: I try with "python3 consumer.py | less or head", but the script didn't work.

Comment: It’s worth mentioning that [`less` can be tricked into reloading the current file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4361/246819).

Answer (score 1):

There's an option in GNOME Terminal's Profile Preferences: [Scroll on output](https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-terminal/stable/pref-scrolling.html.en#on-output). By default it's unchecked, and the effect is that, when a command is producing continuous output, and you scroll up at least *once*, then the terminal will not automatically scroll down to the latest line of output.

Unfortunately, you still do need to scroll up once when the output starts to trigger this behaviour. If that's not workable, using a pager like `less` is the best option.

Comment: I had already activated this option, but it did not work. How can I use less with "python script.py"?

Comment: @sebastianmorales if you check that output, then the terminal will always jump to the last line. You should leave it unchecked and scroll when the output starts. As for `less`, that's in terdon's answer.